# Order rows by column whilst keeping rows with a common column together

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, innodb

### I'm running MariaDB 5.5 which is equivalent to MySQL 5.5.

I have the following test data.

```
CREATE TABLE `dev_test` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `date` DATE NOT NULL , 
    `venue` INT NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `dev_test` (`id`, `date`, `venue`) VALUES (NULL, '2019-08-01', '2'),
                           (NULL, '2019-09-01', '1'), (NULL, '2019-10-01', '2');
INSERT INTO `dev_test` (`id`, `date`, `venue`) VALUES (NULL, '2019-11-01', '3');
```

I wish to order the venues and the events so that the venue of the next event is first, then all other events at that venue. Then the next event that's not all ready listed.

So with this data I want:

```
Event ID 1 - 2019-08-01 Venue 2
Event ID 3 - 2019-10-01 Venue 2
Event ID 2 - 2019-09-01 Venue 1
Event ID 4 - 2019-11-01 Venue 3
```

I could just grab all the events in any order then order them using PHP.

Or I could select with

```
SELECT venue FROM `dev_test` GROUP BY venue ORDER BY date;
```

Then using PHP get the venues one at a time ordered by date

```
SELECT * FROM `dev_test` WHERE venue = 2 ORDER BY date;
SELECT * FROM `dev_test` WHERE venue = 1 ORDER BY date;
```

But is there a nice way in pure MySQL (MariaDB) to do this?
Maybe some way of giving all venues a temp date column that is the same as the earliest date at that venue?
Or should I just do it in PHP?

Sorry for the title gore. I tried to make "Order events by date whilst keeping events at the same location together" more generic.

Comment: @Strawberry could you expand on that?

Comment: Are dates unique?

Comment: @strawberry Unique dates can't be guaranteed. But it wouldn't matter which order duplicate dates are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, I think this helps you

```
SELECT t2.* FROM 
(SELECT venue FROM dev_test GROUP BY venue ORDER BY date) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dev_test ORDER BY date) AS t2 ON t1.venue=t2.venue
```

Here result

[image]

Comment: This just gives me the events in date order. I tried removing the "ORDER BY date" in the select as t2 but that didn't change anything. Thanks though!

Comment: Ah sorry it clearly does work. It's not working on my database so I'll see if it's a different version or something.

Comment: That's all right. Maybe data in your local database slightly different than here?

Comment: I'm running MariaDB 5.5 which is equivalent to MySQL 5.5. So potentially that difference between MySQL 5.5 and 5.6 is what's wrong.

Comment: This works great on MySQL 5.5+. Not working on Server version: 5.5.60-MariaDB - MariaDB Server. Will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions with CTEs to achieve this (note: Requires MySQL 8+:

```
WITH added_initial_date 
 AS (SELECT id, 
            date, 
            venue, 
            FIRST_VALUE(date) 
              OVER( 
                PARTITION BY venue 
                ORDER BY date) AS 'initial_date' 
     FROM   dev_test), 
 ranked 
 AS (SELECT id, 
            date, 
            venue, 
            initial_date, 
            RANK() 
              OVER( 
                ORDER BY initial_date ASC) AS position 
     FROM   added_initial_date) 
SELECT id, 
   date, 
   venue 
FROM   ranked 
ORDER  BY position ASC, date ASC;
```

Maybe it is not most effective, but it works.

UPDATE: added ordering by date to get closest record first. Here is db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/puYqhDF53ocRiRys61XH53/0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will have to trust that that works for people running MySQL 8+. Sorry I didn't include my DB version in the question originally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using `order by venue desc, date asc`

```
SELECT * FROM `dev_test` 
order by venue desc, date asc
```

Comment: Exatly use multiple order as like he said

Comment: This works with the test data as it is. But if you switch all the venues then it fails as it always returns the highest venue first.

Comment: I've added another row to the test data to show why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. :

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM dev_test a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM dev_test ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) b 
    ON b.venue = a.venue 
 ORDER 
    BY b.id IS NULL, date DESC;
```

This assumes dates are UNIQUE, as per the sample data

Comment: Which version of MySQL is required for this? It doesn't seem to work in MySQL 5.5 or 5.6 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd0578/2

Comment: @SamDean Looks OK to me. Perhaps the specification need clarification. An extended data set and corresponding result might help.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/puYqhDF53ocRiRys61XH53/1 It just returns the rows with date DESC

Comment: That's because there is only one event at venue 3